# Typescript assign a variable of multi type containing OR ( | ) to single type variable

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a variable that has type of number or string. How can I assign its value to a variable that accepts number only?

```
const id:Record<string, string|number> = {name:3}
let num: Record<string, number>;

num = id; //Shows error here
```

I know there can be javascript work arounds like writing
a conversion function, but I am learning Typescript and want to know if there are `keywords` or typescript specific solutions that are meant to be used in such cases, like `as Record<string,number>`... that can cast it, instead of type assertion

[Here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/LAKAkAxg9gdgzgFwAQEsAmAuASgU2gJzQB5F8UYBzAGiVPIoB8YBXAWwCMd8A+JAXiQBvGAENWODACIAzJIC+oMABscyFqwxJcBYnUpU9FbgG5QZ8Ov6o0xpAHo7cABZQA7nCRd8UfEidccIA) is a link to the code on Typescript playground

Comment: you need to check if id is a number then you can assign safely.

Comment: yes, the code logic leads to the usage line only if it contains a number.

Comment: Then show us the code logic that does that. Usually typescript is pretty smart at narrowing types, but without seeing any of your code it’s not possible to tell why type narrowing didn’t happen.

Comment: Please post that logic.

Comment: "*I want to know if there are keywords or typescript specific solutions that are meant to be used in such cases, like `as number`.*" - yes, that one. Just use `id as number`.

Comment: @Terry I have made the change, sorry for the big change. The code logic now  leads to safe number value type because It's already below a value assignment, which is of number type.

Comment: @Bergi, but that would only be type assertion, without changing the type at all, right? that way if I pass it to a function that requires numerical value, it might encounter error inside.

Comment: @Abraham Why would an  error happen if "*the code logic safely leads to this line only if "id" contains a number value*"?

Comment: @Bergi the error shows on typescript., here is a link for Typescript playground
https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/LAKAkAxg9gdgzgFwAQEsAmAuASgU2gJzQB5F8UYBzAGiVPIoB8YBXAWwCMd8A+JAXiQBvGAENWODACIAzJIC+oMABscyFqwxJcBYnUpU9FbgG5QigPTmEACxxJoaO0qgUUEWiIBmOJQE8kKiJocEgIUKHWKCFK5HawfqieSJLokvawCCLkISJI6pz4SABuIkrMOGbg6vyoaMZIlnDWUADuIVz4UIW2+DhAA

Comment: @Abraham That's probably because it misses the actual code logic that checks the values in the record. And if your logic works but TypeScript doesn't recognise it, then that is the situation where type assertions are appropriate. Still, please post that code so that we can give more concrete advice.

Comment: Ok, thank you. the code doesn't have any part. And I said code logic that ensures it gets numerical type, only because It's directly sits under the assignment of numerical value. currently the code is only this.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you already answered your question, you can cast with the as keyword.

```
num = id as number
```

If you wanted to get fancy you could check the id's type with typeof so something like this

```
if (typeof id === 'number') {
  number = id
}
```

Comment: I would be careful about language here. Something like `as` does not perform a type cast, but rather a type *assertion*. This is very important because TypeScript's types usually have no effect at runtime, unlike in some other languages.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [TypeScript 3.7's Assertion Functions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#assertion-functions), to enforce the checks in the code that didn't eliminated the wrong type:

```
const id:Record<string, string|number> = {name:"3"}
let num: Record<string,string>;

//the code logic safely leads to this line only if "id" contains a number value

declare function isNumId(id: Record<string, string | number>): asserts id is Record<string, string>;

isNumId(id);
num = id; // No longer shows error here
```

Of course, it might be simpler to just tell TS that we are sure of the type:

```
num = id as Record<string, string>; // No longer shows error here
```

Answer (score 0):

The Typescript playground link is bit different than what's in the question:

```
    const id:Record<string, string|number> = {name:"3"}
    let num: Record<string,string>;

    //the code logic safely leads to this line only if "id" contains a number value

    num = id; //shows error here
```

But anyway, there are two quick ways to deal with it:

```
    //One solution:
    
    const id2:Record<string, string> | Record<string,number> = {name:"3"}
    let num2: Record<string,string>;    
    num2 = id2;


    //Antoher solution:

    const id3:Record<string, string|number> = {name:"3"}
    let num3: Record<string,string>;
    num3 = id as Record<string,string>;
```

https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/LAKAkAxg9gdgzgFwAQEsAmAuASgU2gJzQB5F8UYBzAGiVPIoB8YBXAWwCMd8A+JAXiQBvGAENWODACIAzJIC+oMABscyFqwxJcBYnUpU9FbgG5QigPTmEACxxJoaO0qgUUEWiIBmOJQE8kKiJocEgIUKHWKCFK5HawfqieSJLokvawCCLkISJI6pz4SABuIkrMOGbg6vyoaMZIlnDWUADuIVz4UIW2+BUglWCWAPIwdnBQZQgosBiKitDwyOgATNh4XboIZPq0W-S8DFrrhCR7+vlcvALCYhIy8ooqamyrRzqn29SGJmCK6ss1FamfogwbmACCMDCPVoE2YUxmAwWiFq0jW70MNEMTDYBSuQlE4iksgU4CeeTYaLeGw+9AMZyMwLA6mkgLQSBEIW0NMx33qlSAA

Answer (score -1):

Just use `Number()`.

TypeScript provides static type checking, but those types don't have any effect at runtime. Doing something like `as` asserts to TypeScript about a variable's type, but it will not actually perform a "cast." If you want your string to be parsed into a number, this will not work.

Comment: But that wouldn't correct the type while passing, instead is a type assertion that will let the line pass

Comment: @Abraham that's exactly what I'm saying. This person needs to use `Number()` to actually parse the string.